Supabase client always returns results, despite the do-not-match filter
This is the query I use with the JS client:
const usersTwitterHandles = ['asd', 'dsa', 'foo', 'bar']
const handlesList = usersTwitterHandles.map((handle) => `'${handle}'`).join(',')

const { data, error } = await supabaseClient
        .from('users')
        .select('*')
        .not('twitter_handle', 'in', `(${handlesList})`)

However, the query always returns results, even though it should not. I even tried to run the equivalent SQL query against the table, and it worked fine.
Am I building the query wrongly? What would be a good debugging technique for the client? As far as I know, it's an API call, not a direct SQL query, so I guess I cannot see the actual SQL that's being executed against the DB.
